# Blurry BitmapCache

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

### The Problem

As visible in the following picture, when I have the height of the `ScrollViewer` content set to 1056px (100%) the text and lines are sharp.

[image: 100X Zoom]

However, when I set the height of the content to 6336px (600%) the text and lines are really blurry.

[image: 600X Zoom]

I am setting the `CacheMode` property of the content to a `BitmapCache` with default settings. I'm not sure if this is applicable, but the height is controlled by a `Binding`.

### The Question

Is there a way to somehow refresh the `CacheMode`? I understood that changes to child layout properties should trigger an automatic refresh, but for some reason this is not working in my case. Or is the problem maybe just the graphics card?

### What I've Tried

- I set the `CacheMode` to `null` and then to a new `BitmapCache`.
- I set the `RenderAtScale` property of the `BitmapCache`.
- I ran calls to `InvalidateProperty(CacheModeProperty)` and `UpdateLayout`.

### The Code

```
<Friction:FrictionScrollViewerControl x:Class="App.Controls.Panes.Calendar.Day.HourlyClockChartDay"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App.Controls.WeekView"
        xmlns:Friction="clr-namespace:App.Controls.Friction" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="400"
        d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="ClockChart_Loaded" Focusable="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        PreviewMouseWheel="scrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" VerticalSnapToValue="22">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="1056">
        <Grid.CacheMode>
            <BitmapCache />
        </Grid.CacheMode>
        <Grid x:Name="clockGrid" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="clockGridCol0" Width="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <controls:ClockGrid x:Name="clockGridBg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="96" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="radioGrid" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=clockGridCol0, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Setter Property="GroupName" Value="_dayGridRadios" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
                    <EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="RadioButton_Checked" />
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Transparent" />
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rect" Value="{DynamicResource CheckedDate}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="itemsGrid" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=grid, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,11,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=clockGridCol0, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Border x:Name="currentTime" Background="{DynamicResource TimeSliderBackground}"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TimeSliderBorder}" BorderThickness="0,1" Height="3"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Border BorderBrush="#FFE1E1E1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    </Grid>
</Friction:FrictionScrollViewerControl>
```

And the C# which sets the height:

```
grid.Height = (int)((int)(1056 * percent) / 528) * 528;
```

Comment: Did you try BitmapScalingMode at window level ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aybe That didn't work.

Comment: Post a small code example reproducing the issue so we can try on our sides.